# if you have a perl script ready (in windows), what's the best way to run it from command line 100 times say and collect the data it produces?

Tags: perl, command-line, batch-file, command-prompt

I have written a perl script in Windows, which produces a line or two of output.

I'd like to be able to run the script n=100 times over, say, from the command line without doing more coding in the script (unless there's an easy way to do that) and collect the output? I've been suggested a batch file might be in order?

Basically, is there an easy way to:

`[perl script.pl >> output + [Enter Key]] # n times in cmd`

Thanks!

Comment: Just use a `for` loop inside your script.

Comment: Or make another script that calls your original script.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a FOR loop in a batch file:

```
for /L %%N IN (1, 1, 100) DO perl script.pl >> output.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Just wrap a for loop around your code:

```
#!/your/perl

for ( my $i = 0; $i < 100; $i++ ) {
    # YOUR ORIGINAL PERL CODE HERE
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I am getting repeat outputs. The only thing that I can think cd be causing this is that in my code I use 'srand(time¦$$)' to seed random numbers. Is it just the processing is too quick which is causing the repeats?

Comment: First, `perl` already does seed the PRNG for you with the exact same low quality seed. If you are going to use a time based seed, at least try [Time::HiRes](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Time::HiRes). However, if you care about the quality of your simulation, you must make sure seeds are saved so the simulation is replicable. If you care about the quality of the PRNG, [don't use `rand`](http://blog.nu42.com/2010/09/be-vary-of-using-built-in-rng-for.html). Choose a PRNG whose properties are known good.